# Cannot interpret '0' as a data type

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I try to convert a datafram's column having "object" as datatype into float.

I use the following code:

```
cam_dev_index_num = cam_dev_index['Access to electricity (% of population)'].astype(int(float()))
```

But I have this error: "Cannot interpret '0' as a data type"

Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [do not upload images of code/errors/data when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you for this reminder, it's my second post on stackoverflow...

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input for us to replicate the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`cam_dev_index_num = cam_dev_index['Access to electricity (% of population)'].astype(int).astype(float)`

Or the other way around:

`.astype(float).astype(int)`

Perhaps even only one of the two is needed, just:

`.astype(float)`

Explanation:
`astype` does not take a function as input, but a type (such as `int`).

Comment: Thanks Paul; indeed, .astype(float) was sufficient!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept this answer. This way the community knows this problem was solved.